# In typescript, is there a way to ensure that a function's return type is exhaustive?

Tags: typescript

If you have a const enum like

```
enum Color {
  RED,
  GREEN,
  BLUE,
}
```

You can write a helper and a switch statement,

```
function assertNever(x: never): never {
    throw new Error(`Unexpected object: ${x}`)
}

function toString (key: Color): string {
  switch (key) {
    case Color.RED: return 'Red'
    case Color.GREEN: return 'Green'
    case Color.BLUE: return 'Blue'
    default: return assertNever(key)
  }
}
```

such that if we ever change `Color`, we must change our `toString` implementation.

However, if I go the other way,

```
function fromString (key: string): Color {
  switch (key) {
    case 'Red': return Color.RED
    case 'Green': return Color.GREEN
    case 'Blue': return Color.BLUE
    default: throw new Error(`${key} is not a Color`)
  }
}
```

It is possible that my fromString implememtation may get out of date with my Color enum.

Is there a way to ensure that there exists some path that returns each kind of `Color`? Is there are way to ensure that the range of the function is `Color`?

Comment: Maybe if the color was a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) you could avoid this whole manual serialization

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestion, and find no fault in anyone who adopts this technique, I am happier when enum values are not chosen by the programmer.

Comment: You hopefully realize that the type of `key` in `fromString` is wrong

Comment: No, that was not intentional. Thanks for helping improve this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality which will enforce this for you automatically.  It is not considered an error for the actual return type of a function to be more specific than the declared return type... if a function is declared to return a `string` but actually always returns the particular string `"hello"`, that's fine.  It's only an error to do the reverse, where the function is declared to return the particular string `"hello"` but actually returns a general `string`.

One thing you can do to achieve something like this in general is to let TypeScript infer the return type of a function and then use a compile-time check to make sure it is what you think it is.  For example:

```
// MutuallyExtends<T, U> only compiles if T extends U and U extends T
type MutuallyExtends<T extends U, U extends V, V=T> = true;

// note how the return type is not annotated
function fromString(key: string) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'Red': return Color.RED
    case 'Green': return Color.GREEN
    case 'Blue': return Color.BLUE
    default: throw new Error(`${key} is not a Color`)
  }
  // the next line will error if not exhaustive:
  type Exhaustive = MutuallyExtends<ReturnType<typeof fromString>, Color>
}
```

The above compiles, but the following produces an error because `Color.BLUE` is missing:

```
function fromString(key: string) {
  switch (key) {
    case 'Red': return Color.RED
    case 'Green': return Color.GREEN
    default: throw new Error(`${key} is not a Color`)
  }
  type Exhaustive = MutuallyExtends<ReturnType<typeof fromString>, Color> // error!
//  Color does not satisfy constraint Color.RED | Color.GREEN ---> ~~~~~
}
```

This is, of course, a workaround.  But maybe it will help you or others.  Hope that is of some use; good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is a possible workaround solution that might work for you don't know if I understand correctly what you want to achieve.

You can define a string literal type with all possible color strings. Then when you change the enum you will first need to change the `toString` function which will force you to add another value to the color names type because you will have no value for the new color. This will then break the `fromString` function so you will need to update it for the build to work. This is how the code looks like with the change:

```
enum Color {
  RED,
  GREEN,
  BLUE
}

type ColorName = 'Red' | 'Green' | 'Blue';

function assertNever(x: never): never {
  throw new Error(`Unexpected object: ${x}`);
}

function toString (key: Color): ColorName {
  switch (key) {
    case Color.RED: return 'Red';
    case Color.GREEN: return 'Green';
    case Color.BLUE: return 'Blue';
    default: return assertNever(key);
  }
}

function assertNeverColor(x: never): never {
  throw new Error(`${x} is not a Color`);
}

function fromString (key: ColorName): Color {
  switch (key) {
    case 'Red': return Color.RED;
    case 'Green': return Color.GREEN;
    case 'Blue': return Color.BLUE;
    default: return assertNever(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: This, along with maintaining a map or using a string enum, definitely achieves the goal and in practice I do things like this. However, I would like to accept an answer like: "No, there is no way to ensure that a function's return type is exhaustive. However, here's a workaround..." because my question is about how typescript works, not about how to achieve a particular result using typescript. I've upvoted your answer, but I won't accept it for now because I want to know for sure that there is no exhaustiveness checking for functions with finite ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the values are different (which would be hard anyway to map otherwise), you could do a typed map from the enum to the string, then build a reverse lookup for that and use it in a type safe way.

Here's an example:

```
enum Color {
  RED,
  GREEN,
  BLUE,
}

const ENUM_COLOR_TO_STRING: Record<Color, string> = {
  [Color.RED]: 'Red',
  [Color.GREEN]: 'Green',
  [Color.BLUE]: 'Blue',
}

const COLORS: Color[] = Object.keys(ENUM_COLOR_TO_STRING) as unknown as Color[];

const STRING_COLOR_TO_ENUM: Record<string, Color> = COLORS.reduce<any>((acc, colorEnum) => {
  const colorValue = ENUM_COLOR_TO_STRING[colorEnum]

  acc[colorValue] = colorEnum;

  return acc
}, {})

function fromString(key: string): Color {
  const color: Color | undefined = STRING_COLOR_TO_ENUM[key];

  if (!color) {
    throw new Error(`${key} is not a Color`)
  }

  return color
}
```

Live demo on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwLACgpQEoCiAIgDS5QD0FUADNrgOKEEByZVUAjPVAEIAyAVQJlK1AEzYAvtmwBjOCADOAFyitBAWQD6MAPL89ebQBU92gMom8ASRYMAXPmALkAEwA88JMjKrkAJYgAOYAfFAAvOg8ANreKAB0hEQAuk4A5HjAbukksfHICUwErGlQ6QzIwKC5+YiJAsJl6bwIYMC1WDJY8oqqsAZGFk4FMSmRUHoARgBWLioJANbAAJ5KABQaOvqGxmaW1nYMAJRQAIZKUGAgiyBwAO4g55ejKQDcslgKympWtva6QZ7cxbJxZVyefxBYJkArhKI7IYJKpuMByYAeM4gFahdbrM5yORkBQ+AjgCCnCLhTA4KDffoklAANTObWAEy2gN2pnMfyOMUZyDJkBSn1wBLkAvqyBZbPGUUFwogHx6tKqKjAyCeEukZDQUmOnwAZtc5CoAoooEbkHAIBYVIEQutlisnFCQscRtLorT6WpBV6fFAAD5XEBuYBGoLZCZ8gGI4HaLYxF3vMVQAJGqDrACEgtONPIUBUAAsbfcoCBgBWCMgbch1gADAAkaBdUgzlzuajOsGljcNtO6PHVmqegukn3piGACSQwXW1tt9sdC8y2XSx1OHAAtDvwkoS3AwAg3FA3AElAAHBBnFa0XrKGdzuALpd2h3Q9YVKo1LdiKA9wPI8TzPC9r1ve9uC+Ppn3nRcbQ-Vdv1adpN23aggKgQ9j1Pc9LxvO8oEkGCnwQWd4PfFcvxaW85EWdCAKwnDQOLMsHnOcN8IgojG1aAlFk7Ss4B7PsfEbIA)